# Get facebook birthday through PHP 5.0 SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can't get my code to get the 'birthday' of my test account or even my own (no success anywhere!) to echo although from what I have seen I'm requesting it correctly and I have the proper permissions for "user_birthday".

But facebook is sending back an object for that field.

All the other fields work perfectly as you can see on my resulted page.

The pertinent part of the request file

## login.php

`$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                    'app_id' => 'my_actual_app_id',
                    'app_secret' => 'my_actual_secret_code',
                    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
            ]);
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $permissions = ['email', 'user_birthday'];
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('my_actual_url', $permissions);`

The callback file

## login-callback.php

```
`$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                'app_id' => 'my_actual_id',
                'app_secret' => 'my_actual_secret_code',
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
        ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
if (isset($accessToken)) {
    // Logged in!
    // OAuth 2.0 client handler
    echo "<br><br><br> Ok 1 <br>";
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    echo "Ok 2 <br>";
    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken(strval($accessToken));
    echo "Ok 3 <br>";
    $_SESSION['login'] = $longLivedAccessToken;
    echo "Ok 4 <br>";
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);
    $response = $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=id,last_name,first_name,email,birthday');
    //$profile = $response->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    echo "Ok 5 <br>";
    // get response
    echo "Ok 6 <br>";
    $node = $response->getGraphNode();
    echo "Ok 7 <br>";
    $fuid = $node->getField('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
    echo "Ok 8 $fuid <br>";
    $fblastname = $node->getField('last_name');
    echo "Ok 9 $fblastname <br>";
    $fbfirstname = $node->getField('first_name');// To Get Facebook first name
    echo "Ok 10 $fbfirstname <br>";
    $femail = $node->getField('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    echo "Ok 11 $femail <br>";
    $fbirthday = $node->getField('birthday');
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($fbirthday);
    echo "OK 12 $fbirthday <br>";
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
    $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fuid;
    $_SESSION['LASTNAME'] = $fblastname;
    $_SESSION['FIRSTNAME'] = $fbfirstname;
    $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    $test = "perfect";
    // = Db::getInstance()->checkuser($fuid,$fblastname,$fbfirstname,$femail);
    echo "<br><br><br> Ok 13 $test : Wait for refresh <br>";
    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
    // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
}
//header ( "refresh:15; url=index.php?action=map");`
```

## The resulting page of my login-callback.php code

```
`Ok 1 
Ok 2 
Ok 3 
Ok 4 
Ok 5 
Ok 6 
Ok 7 
Ok 8 104975603177961 
Ok 9 Teck 
Ok 10 Pierre 
Ok 11 myemail@gmail.com 

object(Facebook\GraphNodes\Birthday)#21 (5) { ["hasDate":"Facebook\GraphNodes\Birthday":private]=> bool(true) ["hasYear":"Facebook\GraphNodes\Birthday":private]=> bool(true) ["date"]=> string(26) "1955-05-17 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Europe/Paris" }`
```

I have tried converting it to an array and asking for $array_var['birthday'] but that had the same result...(that works with all the other fields though)

There is some way to get to my birthday information, while *it is* there, but I have found nothing in the facebook docs to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getDecodedBody()`. It returns the parsed body of the response as an array.

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=id,last_name,first_name,email,birthday');
$userData = $response->getDecodedBody();
echo $userData['birthday'];
OR
var_dump($userData);
```

[Facebook\FacebookResponse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookResponse/5.0.0)

Comment: This simple fix works perfectly for all the fields, thanks! Except from figuring this on my own from the `var_dump($response)` , is there any information or doc about this method on the internet I should have found?

Comment: After sending a request to the Graph API, the response will be returned in the form of a Facebook\FacebookResponse entity.

[FacebookResponse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookResponse/5.0.0)